# How to make constants in CodeIgniter for images?

Tags: php, codeigniter, constants

I want to use the constants.php file to store common image locations.  I have a menu and each item has an image of it’s own, and currently for each image in the view, I have:

```
<?php echo $this->config->item(‘base_url’); ?>/images/database.png”>
```

Or whatever the filename is.  What I want to do is store a constant “DB_IMG” in this instance, and simply be able to say in my view:

```
<?php echo DB_IMG; ?>
```

I know that I can't put:

```
$this->config->item('base_url')
```

in the constants file (I tried it, it errored out) and I tried:

```
$config('base_url')
```

which said it wasn't defined.  Here's what I'd like to put in my constants file (even though I know this doesn't work) so if you could help me, I'd appreciate it:

```
define('DB_IMG',$this->config->item('base_url').'/images/database.png');
```

Thanks.

Comment: $config is an array, try $config['base_url']

Comment: Incidentally, you don't actually need the full URL if the images are on the same domain as the page they appear on.  You can just use `/images/database.png` rather than `<?php echo $this->config->item(‘base_url’); ?>/images/database.png”>`

Comment: I'll give this a try, hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because constants.php is in the config directory it doesn't have access to config items because config.php hasn't been loaded yet.  I think you'll need to put the full URL in there or else use native PHP functions to get the base URL.

Comment: That's a good point by Endophage.  You shouldn't need to even set the base_url for image paths since everything is relative to the root index.php file.

Answer (score 3):

try this
in constants.php

```
require APPPATH . 'config/config' . EXT;

define(BASE_URL, $config['base_url']);
define(DB_IMG, $config['base_url'] . '/images/database.png');  

unset($config);
```